# Relative topology

Tags: general-topology

The entire set is clopen in a relative topology, so it ought to contain all of it's limit points and all of its points ought to be interior right?
I need two examples done:

- 1st, a circle $C$ which i know is open because all of its points are interior. It vacuously should contain all of its limit points too and be clopen. *Another thing, is there really a radius 2 disc at the center of this circles own topology since it is open? someone told me there is but didnt reply to me*
- Second, an 'interval' $ ( \; - \; 1 \; , \; 1 \; )$ which is open as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ but it is clopen relative to is own topology because it 'intersects with $[ \; - \; 1 \; , \; 1 \; ]$'; the way i am reading it is not as even containing $-1$ or $1$.... that is evidently wrong. So as the unit interval with those included how can all of its points be interior when there is no neighborhood around either end???? It also should contain its limit points if i remember correctly..

That is all thanks..

Comment: You’re getting confused by points in the ambient space not in the subspace, which are irrelevant for understanding the subspace topology. To understand the subspace topology delete everything that isn’t the subspace from your visualization.

Answer (score 1):

1. Let us determine the open balls $N_r(p) = N_r(p,C)$ around points $p \in C \subset \mathbb R^2$. For the sake of simplicity let us assume that $C = \{ x \in \mathbb R^2 \mid \lvert x \rvert = 1 \}$ is the unit circle. If $r > 2$, then $N_r(p) = C$. If $r \le 2$, then the circle $C_r(p) = \{ x \in \mathbb R^2 \mid \lvert x - p \rvert = r \}$ intersects $C$ in $-p \in C$ when $r = 2$ and in two points $a, b \in C$ when $r < 2$.  $N_r(p)$ contains all points of $C$ which are inside of $C_r(p)$ (excluding of course the intersection points). Thus $N_r(p)$ is an open circular arc which you may imagine as on open interval of length $\le 2\pi$ wrapped around $C$. Moreover, any open ball (= open disk in that case) $N_r(x,\mathbb R^2)$ in $\mathbb R^2$ intersects $C$ in an open subset of $C$. This intersection is either empty or $C$ or an open circular arc. For $x = 0$ you have $N_r(0,\mathbb R^2) \cap C = \emptyset$ for $r \le 1$ and $N_r(0,\mathbb R^2) \cap C = C$ for $r > 1$. For all $x \ne 0$ you additionally get open circular arcs for suitable $r$.
2. The open balls in $(-1,1) \subset \mathbb R$ are precisely the open subintervals of $(-1,1)$. $\pm1$ cannot be limit points **in the space $(-1,1)$** simply because they do not belong to it. However, they are limit points of the subset $(-1,1)$ in the bigger space $\mathbb R$.

You must carefully distiguish between the topology of a subspace and the topology of the ambient space.